# Extensive update statements

Tags: java, android, database

I have a cook  recipes  application about 4000  stored in database , When the user opens the app i have a ViewPager that displays single recipe and while scrolling he will get new recipe , what i want if the user close the app and reopen it i want to show recipes that he didn't see before .

what i have tried so far

in my recipe TABLE     `( _id , name , content , view_rank)` i put `view_rank` field starts with the value of `0` so if when the viewpager displays this recipes it will increment the `view_rank`  so in my Query i make this

`SELECT * FROM RECIPES ORDER BY view_rank ASC` so i got new ones . any way each increment cause the app to fire a new thread to update the database , what i am thinking about  is to implement a custom buffer  that holds id of recipes that need to increment , so if the buffer reach it limit lets say 100 id i will start a new thread and make a transaction to update those 100 id's . is there a simple solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `ArrayList` and add the `_id` in to it when the user scrolls through the results in your `ViewPager`. I assume that you are rolling through the pages using a button so when you click on that button add the `_id` to the `ArrayList`, also check if the size of the `ArrayList` is 100 using the method `size()`. If the size is 100 walk through the list and update the database.

The API for `ArrayList` is here [Array List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

--EDIT--
When you do this don't forget to update the result to database on closing the application. Otherwise if the counter does not hit 100 the database update never happens and on the next start you will see the visited records again..

Comment: sorry about that.. i just put it in more explained form.. i have just identified `ArrayList` here.. Nothing much!! and do you want to show already shown records at all ??